# Appexchange Tiered Pricing

Tags: appexchange

Is it possible to create an Appexchange app with multiple pricing tiers? Everything I have seen has said it only supports one single price point.

IE Gold -$20
Silver - $10
Bronze - $5

Answer (score 1):

Each package supports one of three models: free, cost per site, and cost per user. The License Management Application doesn't support multiple tiers of functionality; either a user can use the app or they cannot. The usual way that I've seen this handled is to have multiple packages; one base package with all the functionality built-in, but partially disabled without additional package installations, and various extra or extension packages that can be detected by the base package to enable extra features. Each package can then be managed in the LMA independently. It'll cost more in security review fees, etc, but the net licensing model will remain the same. You'll want to contact Partner Support for specifics on how they'll want you to set this up.

Comment: Gotcha. So basically the way to go about it is to create multiple packages, and when they want to 'upgrade', direct users to install those separate packages to enable the functionality..and that will control the cost. Thank you, that's what I was thinking was the only way to accomplish this, but I just wanted to make sure that that was the case.

Comment: We use feature keys to enable the tiers. Depending on the package it could be an option. There are downsides though. Iirc DX is supposed to add this via lma at some point right?

Comment: @Eric I haven't seen that in the DX docs, but it makes sense they'd finally enable something like this.

Comment: I know I heard it was coming but can't remember what it is part of lol

Comment: If you are an OEM or ISVForce partner you can may have more flexible options, depending on the details. Worth registering as an ISV and talking to a partner account manager further about specifics.